# Calling a function on popup from background. (Google Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working in a google chrome extension. I have a function in my popup.js that populates a table **update_table**. I want to call that function from my background.js that sends the important data. The problem is the the update_table on background.js is not define and if i copy the code into that file dont update the table on popup.html.

**popup.js**

```
function update_table(content, morecontent){
  if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
      tabBody=document.getElementsByTagName("tbody").item(0);
      row=document.createElement("tr");
      cell1 = document.createElement("td");
      cell2 = document.createElement("td");
      textnode1=document.createTextNode(content);
      textnode2=document.createTextNode(morecontent);
      <!-- ... -->
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Popup Page</title>
<script src="./popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <table border='1' id='mytable'>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>22</td><td>333</td></tr>
        <tr><td>22</td><td>333</td></tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    function(request) {
        update_table(request.type, request.url);
    },
    {urls: ["*://*/*"]},
    ["responseHeaders"]
);
```

**background.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Background Page</title>
   <script src="./background.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to interact with background.js from the popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537435/how-to-interact-with-background-js-from-the-popup)

Comment: 3 ways: chrome.extension.(getViews, sendRequest or Port)

Answer (score 0):

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537435/how-to-interact-with-background-js-from-the-popup), I just answer this for another person.

Your best bet it to look the [chrome.extension.* API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html). 
I will be posting an example on GitHub some time tomorrow that I can show you.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

[Here you go.](https://github.com/jjNford/chrome-extension-socket) This is a socket script I created that allows continuous communication between a background page and a popup.  There is an example provided in the README.  I currently use this for an extension that passes up to 100 items per instance and it works perfect.  :P