# browserify + chrome extension's getBackgroundPage()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browserify

I'm using browserify to manage a Chrome extension, and while in general it appears to work well, there's a problem that comes with browserify embedding the library code in some wrappers. In particular, when accessing `chrome.extensions.getBackgroundPage()` from a Chrome extension plugin as described, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538625/353337), not all (none?) of the background page's local variables can be accessed. This can be reproduced by anyone by wrapping `background.js` in

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
//[...]
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

as browserify does.

I'm not sure what kind of magic (if any) is behind `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`, but maybe someone else has an idea.

Comment: Please clarify whats the actual question and problem code. The one shown doesnt call get backgroundPage. Also the linked s.o. answer IS correct as it talks about a popup calling it. When it doenst work and requires messaging is when you try to use it from a content or injected script.

Comment: @ZigMandel Thanks for your comment. I tried to clarify the question to make it more easily reproducible for everyone.

Comment: But from where is it calling getBackgroundPage from a popup js or a content or injected js? Must have that to answer

Comment: This is from the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you browserify a module (e.g., `background.js`), it gets wrapped in a function. Hence, all variables declared here in the style of

```
var iii = 123;
```

cannot be accessed from outside, and are in particular not exported to `chrome.extensions.getBackgroundPage()`. All variables that you would like to use elsewhere, *must* be declared `global`, e.g.,

```
global.iii = 123;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Nico's answer, `chrome.extensions.getBackgroundPage()` always was something of a crude hack.

A better approach would be to decouple your popup and background code, and instead pass commands with [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and share data in [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Then this problem does not appear.