# Chrome extension working in background

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension whose goal is to **access a website in the background a display a specific value from it** which the user should see by clicking on the chrome extension icon without having it to open the specific tab.

Here's my `popup.html` :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Analyzer</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Current Notifications</h1>
    <a id="myLink" href ="https://website.com/notify/index.php"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my `popup.js` :

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName('notificationArea').item('span').childNodes[6].textContent; // this is the value which I want to display on click of the extension icon

window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML=a; 
} // Here, trying to add the value to the popup.html element
```

If I try to popup as an alert box on the specific website tab, it works. But not in background when the website tab is not open.

So two problems here :

1. How can I make the extension able to access the website contents in the background ?
2. How can I show the javascript content from popup.js in the popup.html

Answer (score 0):

## Question #1

You could use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to access web pages, get the info and pass it to `background page` via [messaging passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

## Question #2

### Part I

It is the same with question #1 in fact. The following code should belong to `content script`

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName('notificationArea').item('span').childNodes[6].textContent; // this is the value which I want to display on click of the extension icon
```

### Part II

Then you can use "message passing" cited above to pass it from `content script` to `background page`.

And since `popup.js` and `background page` both live in the extension process, there are many ways to communicate between each other. You can refer to previous post for more details. [How to communicate between popup page and background page and store the info that I already get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861311/how-to-communicate-between-popup-page-and-background-page-and-store-the-info-tha/35861740#35861740)

### Part III

Finally you can use your code in `popup.js` to set the text of the link.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML=a; 
} // Here, trying to add the value to the popup.html element
```

## Appendix

To get the value you want to display, you can also just make a ajax call to the website, query the returned DOM and retrieve the data you want. All this can be done via popup.js. Sample code would look like

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    callback: function (data) {
        var mydata = $(data).find('You css selector');
        document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML=mydata; 
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't like this answer for only mentioning ("you need to") content scripts as a possibility to scrape information off pages. Often (but not always) XHR can solve this without having to open a tab.

Comment: @Xan, thanks for mentioning that, I'll update the answer