# How to trigger some action from background.js when popup opens in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension. I need to run a js script when the popup opens. How can I do that from background.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interact with background.js from the popup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537435/how-to-interact-with-background-js-from-the-popup)

Answer (score 4):

I am almost sure that this has already been asked and answered here, but it was easier to write it again than to find the existing question. You need to use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "Start action in background from popup.",
  "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "My extension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["event.js"]
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Background page has been notified</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text: "popup opened"});
```

**event.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
    if (message.text == "popup opened") {
        console.log ("Popup says it was opened.");
        // Run your script from here
    }
});
```